# Suggestions and feature requests for the design of a font for math articles/books

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-writing, latex

**A little context and introduction:** I'm currently working on a family of fonts ("Darwin") designed for use in formal writing and optimised in particular for use in mathematics articles, books, etc. It is meant to fill the following requirements, which no currently available fonts for LaTeX fill:

1. It must be completely free and open-source.
2. It must have exceptional symbol coverage among many different languages, covering essentially all languages making use of the Latin, Cyrillic, and Greek alphabets.
3. It must come with a number of [*optical sizes*](https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/glossary/optical_sizes), which are additional font families with size-specific optimizations―think an extra font for footnotes, a font for usual paragraph text, and an extra font for book covers.
4. It must come with a matching math font family to uniformise the style across the document. This includes all the usual math symbols as well as font families for `\mathbb`, `\mathsf`, etc.

Currently the regular style of the font looks like this (please ignore the currently uneven spacing):
[image]

I have also prepared PDF samples of articles in English, Russian, and Greek compiled using the current version of the font, though please note that these contain only the regular style of the text version, and currently have very uneven spacing:

1. **English Sample:** [Bhatt–Lurie's *The prismatization of $p$-adic formal schemes*](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IoV8xaavZ3BF7H2I-LWJqxydMy9GTIzq/view?usp=sharing). Original: [arXiv:2201.06124](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.06124).
2. **Russian Sample:** [Sergei Akbarov's *Stereotype Dualities in Geometry*](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C5G70kMTEIsY7D7dDKf8RAC_WlS5knII/view). Original: [arXiv:2311.05131](https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.05131).
3. **Greek Sample:** [Grigorios Tachyridis's *Krylov subspace methods for the solution of linear Toeplitz systems*](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12cIKc3-fvvxNkANINBl7g_sKQWeV0qKP/view). Original: [arXiv:2303.03223](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.03223).

I should also note that these samples were compiled from sources of papers directly downloaded from the arXiv, and as such I bear no relation to their authors.

---

**Now, for the actual question:** Throughout my own research as well as discussions with friends and colleagues, I've often found situations in math which require special symbols or features from fonts/LaTeX packages, as well as distinct preferences when it comes to certain choices of fonts. For example, these include:

1. The use of symbols that are specific to certain areas and not usually covered by the default LaTeX fonts, like:

   a) The hiragana よ for the [Yoneda embedding](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yoneda+embedding) in category theory.

   b) The Cyrillic letter Ш for the [Tate–Shafarevich group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate%E2%80%93Shafarevich_group) in arithmetic geometry.

   c) The Cyrillic letter Л for the [Lobachevsky function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/703836) in hyperbolic geometry.

   d) The Cyrillic letter Э for [evolutionary vector fields](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/evolutionary+vector+field) on a jet bundle in some articles, [e.g. this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410185.pdf#page=14), on the geometry of PDEs, as [pointed out](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5856/suggestions-for-the-design-of-a-font-for-math-articles-books#comment29568_5856) by Igor Khavkine.
2. Better glyph support for `\mathcal`, `\mathbb`, `\mathfrak`, etc., such as:

   a) [`\mathbb` for the lowercase alphabet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254445/package-for-mathbblowercase-letter-symbol).

   b) [`\mathbb` for Greek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/blackboard-bold-variants-for-greek-letters).

   c) More exotic things like `\mathcal` or `\mathfrak` for Greek.
3. A preference of "empty fill" (`txof` style) over double-strucked blackboard bold (`amsbb` style) or vice versa, so that having both versions available in a font would be nice:

[image]

vs.

[image]

4. A bigger set of delimiters, as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/483976), for situations where one would e.g. need parentheses bigger than `\big(...\big)` but smaller than `\Big(...\Big)`.
5. Variable size delimiters for doubled parentheses `((...))`, doubled brackets `[[...]]` and doubled angle brackets `<< ... >>`, a [feature request by Willie Wong](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5856/suggestions-for-the-design-of-a-font-for-math-articles-books?cb=1#comment29579_5864).
6. Native and easy handling of bold text and bold math for section and chapter headers, a [feature request by Apoorv Potnis](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5856/suggestions-for-the-design-of-a-font-for-math-articles-books?cb=1#comment29586_5864).
7. [Built-in optimisation of microtype through a variable width axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634421/), allowing for an even better spacing optimisation than microtype already wonderfully does.
8. Symbols for binary relations that are missing from current LaTeX packages, such as [inequality versions of $\asymp$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591161/inequality-counterparts-of-asymp), a [feature request by Iosif Pinelis](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463883/suggestions-and-feature-requests-for-the-design-of-a-font-for-math-articles-book?noredirect=1#comment1204439_463883).

I plan to address all these points and more in the development of Darwin, but I'm sure the above list is anything but exhaustive, and there ought to be countless more such features which would benefit the community. So, in the spirit of the items above, I'd like to ask: **are there any font features you want to have as part of your work, but weren't available or required workarounds at the time you thought of them?**

Here "features" should be understood as including things in the spirit of the above examples, but not limited to them.

I also want to point out that suggestions without technical details are more than welcome. Part of the reason I wanted to ask this question on MO instead of somewhere like TeX.SE is that I believe mathematicians not familiar with type design or the technicalities of LaTeX surely also have extremely valuable feedback to offer. So, for example, suggestions like "this symbol sketched by pencil below would work great for doing [x] in area [y], but I'm not aware of an implementation of it, or find the current ones flawed because of [reason]" would also be exceedingly welcome.

Comment: Incidentally, there's another font project which I believe is going to fill the "font gap" outlined above once it is finished: [Linus Romer's Elemaints typeface](https://typedrawers.com/discussion/2630/elemaints-a-serif-family-with-optical-sizes). In this case, Darwin will then work as an additional option with a significantly different style, similarly to Computer Modern vs. Palatino or Libertine.

Comment: See also the MO meta discussion for this question, which preceded it: [Link](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5856/suggestions-for-the-design-of-a-font-for-math-articles-books).

Comment: I don't understand point (3), about "empty fill".  Could you say more?  Does one of the examples illustrate it?  (Is `txof` the name of your font?  I do not find it on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/search?phrase=txof).)

Comment: @LSpice Sorry if that was confusing! I've edited the question to clarify ``txof`` and ``amsbb`` are meant to be illustrative examples of "empty fill" blackboard bold vs. "double strucked" blackboard bold. ``txof`` is a blackboard bold font implemented by the [mathalpha package](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha), see [here](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf#page=11).

Comment: [Inequality counterparts of `\asymp`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591161/inequality-counterparts-of-asymp) are, strangely, missing in available LaTeX packages, but I guess this is not a matter of fonts.

Comment: I like AMS bb more than tx of.

Comment: @IosifPinelis It is a matter of fonts! I'll be sure to add these too then, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @IosifPinelis As for AMS bb vs txof, I'll add both versions to the font, with AMS bb being the default (I like it more too, and believe it is usually the preferred option among the two).

Comment: Thank you Emily for your responses. Will there be a way to follow major steps in the development of the Darwin project?

Comment: The font is a wonder. Now all your examples look entirely set in bold weight. I cannot believe it is going to be the regular style you mention.

Comment: In item 2, [`\mathbb` for digits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/) would also be nice.

Comment: @IosifPinelis It's my pleasure, thank *you* for the suggestions! I'm currently working on a GitHub pages website for the project where I'll post updates and some other things; I'll link to it here once it's ready :)

Comment: @ClaudeChaunier This is a point I'm currently experimenting a bit with: it's quite common for digital revivals of fonts (e.g. Garamond) to be overly light when compared to their "metal type" counterparts, due to sometimes overcompensating for ink spread during the digitization process, as well as making the typefaces lighter so that they work well when printed due to ink spread again, which tends to make text appear bolder when it's printed on paper, specially with low-quality printers.

Comment: But since so much text today often remains digital and is almost never printed (like arXiv preprints) and since printing quality today is so much higher on average than before, there have been a number of typefaces released recently that are quite a bit darker than usual, a somewhat “famous” example of this being [Arno](https://typographica.org/typeface-reviews/arno/).

Comment: Here's what I plan to do for Darwin with respect to all this: first, I plan to make a considerably lighter version of the regular style and then test a number of interpolated versions between the two (via variable fonts) to identify the best weight choice for reading it digitally, which will then become the new and final Regular style. Second, I plan to implement a "printing" option for the Darwin package, called like `\usepackage[printing]{darwin}`, that will render an appropriately lighter version of the font intended to give the best result for printing.

Comment: Overall though, I do feel that the current Regular style is a bit too dark/bold; the final one will most likely be a little lighter.

Comment: @indicator Right! I've often found these painful to get to work nicely in LaTeX, and the ones available (like those from `\mathbbol`) often don't match the style of the other fonts. I'll be sure to add them too, thank you very much for the suggestion!

Comment: Does the world really need another serif font? Sad-face-emoji.

Comment: Seeing the votes on the discussion on Meta, it is my impression that the community voted for alternative ways of gathering feedback rather than for a post on the main site.

Comment: @Stian Yes. Incidentally, the font will come with a sans-serif counterpart of matching style as well.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Ah, I interpreted it as support of the idea of having a GitHub repository/a website as an additional way to gather feedback, albeit not necessarily the only one. I also took the +5 vs. -2 vote on the question draft I posted there as indicative that it would be a good idea, and I think this seems to have been the right decision considering the good reception the question has had so far, as well as the wonderful suggestions I've received so far, of which I'm very thankful.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Perhaps it would have been a good idea however to explicitly post an answer there asking to upvote/downvote it according to whether one was in favor of it being asked here, as has been done before with some questions on the MO meta, such as [this one](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5818/).

Comment: The Russian sample looks very nice and is much more legible than the usual, which I guess is Computer Modern or some variant.

Comment: @Emily I am not a native English speaker, but if I understand correctly "alternative" means "do this instead of that", while "additional" would have meant "do both this and that". In my (possibly wrong) understanding, Willie Wong's answer was a politely phrased "No, the question is inappropriate" option.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning I'm really happy to hear so! Throughout the development of the Cyrillic portion of the font I've been working hard to make it as "warm", "clean", and "legible" as I can, and it's really amazing to hear this came through in the current result. Thank you so much for your comment, Elizabeth! =)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Ah, my apologies then.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni My impression was that Willie Wong was being neutral on the question of whether the question was suitable for MO. But your reading could be correct. As for English usage, I agree that "alternative" often (though not always) carries the connotation of "one or the other but not both". However, if I suggest an alternative, it does not necessarily mean that I am recommending it; sometimes I am just generating options for consideration.

Comment: @Emily I wanted to take look at your work, but following your website, the links "Papers" and "Fonts" currently lead to "404 File not found" pages.

Comment: @xamid Thank you so much for your kind interest! I started building my website a while ago, but it's still under construction, hence the current 404 errors. Thank you also for the heads-up; I'm hoping to update and fix those pages as soon as I can.

Comment: Not very important but let me remark that the prism symbol is missing in your rendering of Bhatt-Lurie. (Check the third line of the introduction in the arXiv version and compare the Spf(Z_p)_\prism with what appears in your rendering.)

Comment: Just to add to the doublestruck discussion, there is another style, provided by the dsfont package (doublestroke font https://ctan.org/pkg/doublestroke?lang=en) for computer modern. It is used by fonts such as kpfonts, newcm, linux libertine, concmath-otf, minion, etc. Some Times Roman matching variants are discussed in the newtx documentation as well. This comment is just for info, as creating one more style for \mathbb characters would be a very time consuming task on your end.

Comment: One more comment regarding the weights of fonts. Fonts in general look heavier on mac os, or any apple device. A font would in general look lighter on windows, linux or android devices, compared to mac os. For example, I find the default Latin Modern very light (on windows/linux) but find it nice on mac os. So, the perception of font weight will also depend on the particular operating system used for rendering, along with the specific choice of pdf reader. I can provide with screenshots on the same device with different OSes, if needed.

Comment: @Gabriel Thanks for letting me know, I've fixed the sample now! Come to think of it, `\prism` is another example of a symbol that requires some tinkering with LaTeX and is not available by default (not to mention mathbbol Greek has a different style than the text font).

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Thanks for the reminder on the `dsfont` package! Thinking about it, there are probably quite a few different approaches to designing `\mathbb`, besides the traditional way as in `amsbb`, carved out as in `txof`, double-strucked as in `dsfont`, vertical lines as in ["`mathpi`" here](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf#page=11), etc., specially if you consider fonts not related to LaTeX, such as those [here](https://www.fontspace.com/category/double-struck) (though surely there are better listings of such fonts out there).

Comment: I think one way to proceed might be to enumerate such styles and query people about them to decide which styles are the most popular/desired. Given the number of glyphs required for a full-fledged `\mathbb` (uppercase and lowercase Latin, numbers, Greek, Cyrillic, etc.), designing all styles would probably require too much work unfortunately (at least for an initial release), but designing a couple different styles (say `amsbb`, `txof`, and `mathpi`) might still be reasonable (and desirable from the point of view of the user) I think

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Thank you also for letting me know about the weight issue on macOS! I'm not very familiar with mac-based devices as they are way sadly way too expensive where I live, but lately I have been considering building a hackintosh for macOS to be able to use some font software that is only available for macOS devices (namely [Glyphs](https://glyphsapp.com/)). I think being able to directly test the weight difference would then be yet another good point to consider for doing this

Comment: Lastly, let me thank thank you once again, Apoorv, I truly appreciate your suggestions and notes; they'll be super helpful when designing the font!

Comment: (Also, let me apologise for taking a little bit to reply this time around; I had to deal with some life stuff that precluded me from replying sooner)

Comment: I guess item 5 (about `[[...]]`... ) should also include `{{...}}`. On the other hand I don't know if there is any existing use of triple parentheses/brackets/etc $[\![\![\dots]\!]\!]$ but one might want to make it available.

Comment: @YCor Right, I'll be sure to implement `{{...}}` too! I haven't ever seen "tripled" delimiters before either, but I could very well see them being reasonably used in practice, I'll be sure to add them too :)

Comment: One more thing that I forgot to mention, but most likely you are already aware of this. One cannot use too many math alphabets in a single document in pdflatex. I think only 16 math fonts (mathgroups?) are possible. I don't know any workarounds around this, but the newtx package offers a lot of glyphs, you can check its coding for some trickery or compromises it does while loading math fonts.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Thanks for letting me know! This will certainly be an issue for the `pdflatex` version of the font. My current plan for this is to sweep all the trickery I'll surely need in the font package, hopefully having the user have to deal with nothing of this.

Answer (score 10):

Here is my own personal wish list (or rather a partial one, consisting of the items I can come up with off the top of my head). Some of them have existing workarounds, and some of them are perhaps not directly solvable by creating a new font, but I figure it's better to err on the side of making suggestions that may not be useful, than to not say anything at all.

- Regarding blackboard bold, I personally prefer a style with vertical rather than curvy lines, such as in the title of [this old paper of mine](http://timothychow.net/distances.pdf).
- You didn't mention Hebrew letters; these are used to denote infinite cardinalities. As mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170476), the default $\aleph$ and $\beth$ do not have a uniform appearance.
- There does exist a symbol for the wreath product of two groups: $G\wr H$, but I think I'm not alone in finding it unsatisfactory, having a somewhat nondescript appearance. When I first encountered the wreath product symbol in Nathan Jacobson's book *Basic Algebra I*, it looked a lot more like a reverse integration symbol.  See [page 79](https://books.google.com/books?id=JHFpv0tKiBAC&pg=PA79):
  [image: Jacobson's symbol for wreath product]
  I don't know what other people think of that version, but I think it's better than $\wr$. Some circumstantial evidence that people don't really like $\wr$  includes: (1) I often see people writing $\text{wr}$ for the wreath product, which is pretty weird if you think about it (offhand, I can't think of any other product that people represent using two Latin characters), and (2) in Richard Stanley's book *Enumerative Combinatorics Volume 2*, he uses the symbol $\S$ instead (which I don't particularly like either, but at least it's more distinctive than $\wr$).
- There are three [graph products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_product) that are closely related to each other: $G\times H$, $G\boxtimes H$, and $G\mathbin{\square} H$. I had to kludge the last one using `\mathbin\square` (as of this writing, Wikipedia doesn't even bother with `\mathbin` and so it looks even worse). Admittedly, this kludge works reasonably well, but I think it would look nicer if the three symbols all had the same size (compare $\times \otimes$ with $\times \boxtimes$), which they currently don't.
- Sometimes one wants a [modified summation symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/635008), e.g.,
  $$\mathop{{\sum}'}_{m,n} {1\over (mz + n)^{2k}}.$$
  This is discussed in Exercise 18.44 of Knuth's original $\rm\TeX book$, where he points out that the above solution `\mathop{{\sum}'}` centers the limits on the primed summation sign rather than the original summation sign. The workaround for that is much more complicated. I don't think that it's necessary to create separate symbols for every possible accent that someone might want to decorate the summation symbol with; offhand, I think I've only ever seen $\sum'$ and $\sum^*$. An example of the former may be found in Jean-Pierre Serre's book *A Course in Arithmetic*, Chapter VII, Section 2.3.
- Sometimes I want to put an arrow over something to indicate that it's a vector. If I just want a rightward-pointing arrow then `\vec` is usually fine; e.g., $\vec v$. But if I want an arrow going in the opposite direction, then the only easy solution I know is to use `\overleftarrow`, as in $\overleftarrow{v}$, which is clumsy. Using a harpoon instead of an arrow looks a bit more elegant to me, but seems to be [complicated to implement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304622). It would nice if extensible arrows or harpoons in both directions were easily implemented.
- There are many different ways that people like to write the [symbol for a disjoint union](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3964). Some are well supported; others are less so. I don't have particularly strong feelings on the topic but thought I would mention it because it does seem to come up a lot.

Comment: Just so that you know: the homegrown implementation of LaTeX on Wikipedia in theory supports `\mathbin`, `\mathrel`, and the like, but in practice they have no effect, because due to a mindbogglingly stupid design decision, the parser normalizes LaTeX input such that it puts braces around everything.

Comment: I know it's not the point, but, just for reference (and until we have this new font!), [amsmath](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides $\displaystyle\sideset{}'\sum_{m, n} \frac1{(mz + n)^{2k}}$ `\sideset{}'\sum_{m, n} \frac1{(mz + n)^{2k}}`, and an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/693046) to a [TeXSE question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693044) (which was a [duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15010) suggested an ingenious double-`\reflectbox`, `\reflectbox{$\vec{\reflectbox{\!$v$}}` (obviously best encapsulated as a macro, as in that answer!).

Comment: Thank you so much for putting together such a detailed list of suggestions, Timothy! I truly appreciate it and will be sure to implement all of them!

Comment: Here are some more specific points: 1) I've decided to make all three variations for blackboard bold, chosen with something like `\usepackage[bb=X]{darwin}` with X=`ams`, `txof`, `vertical` (or perhaps names that don't make references to specific fonts, but which describe what the style looks like, such as `curved`, `empty-fill`, and `vertical`. I'll think carefully about this)

Comment: 2) The wreath symbol in Jacobson is *really* interesting; I had never seen it before, but I did feel a bit dissatisfied with the symbol $\wr$ for wreath products. This makes me wonder whether there are similar situations for other symbols, unavailable in LaTeX but nice and useful in practice.

Comment: 3) The unconsistent size for binary symbols like $\mathord{\times}\mathord{\otimes}\mathord{\boxtimes}\mathord{\square}$ had always bothered me too, I think there are probably even more such symbols in practice which could be standardized in size with respect to each other, like e.g. $\mathord{\diamond}$ as in $\mathord{\times}\mathord{\otimes}\mathord{\boxtimes}\mathord{\square}\mathord{\diamond}$.

Comment: 4) Extensible arrows, both as in $\vec{v}$ and $\underset{\scriptsize\to}{v}$ as well as in $A\xrightarrow{f}B$, are another point that always bothered me. There are even a few of these that are used in practice but lack a standard implementation, such as [⇸ for profunctors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/profunctor), Riehl–Verity's arrows as in e.g. [Definitions 1.1.24 and 1.1.25 of their book](https://math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/elements.pdf#page=24), a version of $\rightleftarrows$ with $\dashv$ for adjunctions, and so on. I'll probably end up implementing dozens and dozens of these.

Comment: @Emily, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463883/suggestions-and-feature-requests-for-the-design-of-a-font-for-math-articles-book#comment1204587_463914), do you mean Definition 1.1.23, rather than 1.1.24, of the Riehl–Verity book, as your link suggests?  (Also, I'm not a font designer—is it really better to try to anticipate everyone's arrow-based decorations at one glyph apiece, rather than to provide a flexible way of assembling and modifying arrows?  Or is the latter what you mean, and I've misunderstood?)

Comment: I took the liberty of editing in a screenshot from Jacobson (as well as linking to the actual page on Google Books), for anyone curious as I was about the glyph in question.  I hope that that was all right.

Comment: @LSpice I do, thanks for the correction! Regarding the arrow implementation, I think a good way to approach this might be to have specific implementations of the arrows that are already in common usage (like ⇸) while also making the package compatible with `tikz-cd` (i.e. ensuring the arrows and decorations generated by `tikz-cd` match the font in style), as it would then serve as a powerful engine for making custom arrows of matching style with the font.

Comment: In reponse to "offhand, I can't think of any other product that people represent using two Latin characters", the matrix trace is sometimes denoted $tr$

Comment: @user160623 But the trace is not a product (i.e., a binary operator). After thinking about it a bit more, I seem to recall seeing $\rm sh$ being used for a shuffle product, but (I think) only because the character ш was not available. But even this example just reinforces my impression that people would like a nice symbol for the wreath product and find the current situation suboptimal.

Answer (score 8):

1. Bold versions of the blackboard bold letters.  It's common to want $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ as part of a section heading, e.g.

   $\textbf{Conjugacy classes in $\textbf{GL}_{\boldsymbol{n}}(\mathbb{R})$}$

   and the $\mathbb{R}$ looks out of place because of the stroke weight.
2. If it's possible to make `\overline` align well with characters, that would be helpful.  The default overline alignment is very poor, e.g.
   $$
   \overline{f},\quad \overline{j}, \quad\overline{s}, \quad\overline{A}, \quad\overline{B}, \quad\overline{V}
   $$
   Using `\bar` only fixes some of these, doesn't match the look of `\overline`, and has its own problems with some other letters:
   $$
   \bar{f},\quad \bar{j},\quad \bar{s},\quad \bar{A}, \quad\bar{B},\quad \bar{V}, \quad \bar{d}, \quad \bar{m}, \quad \bar{M}, \quad \bar{T}
   $$
   There are similar issues with `\widehat`.  All of this can be fixed with well-chosen `\mkern`'s, but it should be automatic.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions! I've had so much frustration with `\overline` and similar commands over the years; I remember there was a TeX.SE question with a nice but quite complicated implementation that worked really well for arbitrary math (like $\overline{\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\exp(-x^{2})\,\mathrm{d}x}$), but unfortunately had a tendency to break when used together with certain packages. I'll be sure to implement a easy and nice way to handle all this, as well as appropriate versions of symbols for section headers/titles/etc. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Your comment about blackboard bold makes sense, but I also find it amusing that blackboard bold, which presumably began as a cheap trick to simulate bold letters on a blackboard, is now so entrenched that even on a computer, our instinct is to thicken the lines rather than just use a plain old bold $\mathbf{R}$. It reminds me of someone who would physically tie down his cordless phone so that he wouldn't lose the handset.

Comment: Given that usually different typefaces for letters are used to denote different quantities I am always puzzled if people want variables names in bold in titles. I never do that. A boldface R is not an R and not a blackboard bold R…

Answer (score 8):

Here are the suggestions I can think of

- Legible mathfrak capitals, i.e. easily distinguishable glyphs that resemble their latin counterparts enough that an uninitiated reader can easily tell which one it's meant to be. Like the Mathematica mathfrak I guess. Obviously a balance needs to be struck between legibility and tradition, but I find the illegibility of the default mathfrak adds an unnecessarily barrier to understanding sometimes.
- For mathematical writing it would be nice if punctuation such as parentheses wouldn't be slanted in the textit font. Punctuation doesn't get slanted in math mode, so in theorem-like environments that use italic text you often see a mixture of slanted and upright punctuation and it looks weird, e.g.

[image]

- For specific symbols, conditional independence is represented by something usually written as \perp\!\!\!\perp, as in

[image]

and in category-theoretic probability an arrow with a dot on it is often used for stochastic morphisms, as in

[image]

I guess ideally the dot would be a bit smaller than the \bullet I used here. I don't think either of these exist as a single symbol in any font.

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about "legible mathfrak." Part of the point of Fraktur, or script, is to introduce a symbol that is obviously different from the Latin counterpart. If they look too similar to each other, then that defeats the purpose.  At the same time, I recognize that (for example) $\mathfrak{S}$ looks like an uppercase G to many people. Maybe something like Lucida Fraktur, as shown [here](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf), is a reasonable compromise.

Comment: @TimothyChow $\mathfrak{A}$, $\mathfrak{Y}$ and $\mathfrak{V}$ are all pretty hard to identify as well, and how many people know which is which out of $\mathfrak{J}$ and $\mathfrak{I}$ without looking it up? That Lucida one is pretty legible to me - I don't think I'd have any trouble telling which letter each one is. (Except for the G, which looks like $\mathfrak{S}$.)

Comment: @N.Virgo Thank you so much for your suggestions! I'll be sure to implement all of them :)

Comment: On blackletter, I also find the default font for `\mathfrak` quite confusing for some glyphs. There have been lots and lots of different renderings of blackletter throughout the years; for example, [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Fraktur-Mon-Amour-Judith-Schalansky/dp/156898801X) collects 300 different renderings, and naturally there are even more. I'll be sure to aim for a design that accounts for all these points!

Answer (score 5):

The theme of this answer is "incomplete math fonts".  Most of the special math fonts currently don't even cover the full alphanumeric Latin alphabet (let alone other alphabets):

- `\mathbb` is missing support for lowercase letters (as mentioned in the question) and digits (as mentioned by user @indicator in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463883/suggestions-and-feature-requests-for-the-design-of-a-font-for-math-articles-book#comment1204540_463883), linking to the discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26637/)).
- `\mathcal` is missing support for lowercase letters ([TeX.SE discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479/lowercase-mathcal)) and digits ([TeX.SE discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672424/why-does-putting-a-digit-under-mathcal-display-an-unrelated-symbol)).
- `\mathscr` is missing support for lowercase letters ([TeX.SE discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151549/mathscr-latex-or-xelatex)) and digits.
- … (This answer is community wiki, so others are invited to add any additional examples that fall within this category.)

Arguably, all of these can be considered to be separate fonts, and probably have alternatives in Xe(La)TeX, but it would be nice to have them somehow belong to the same font family and be available in LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'll be sure to add these too :)

Answer (score 4):

Unlike the somewhat obscure scripts you mentioned for particular/unique mathematical symbols, Greek is used constantly in math for all sorts of things. LaTeX has lowercase and uppercase versions of many Greek letters: $\pi$ and $\Pi$, for instance. However, when the uppercase of a Greek letter is identical to its Latin counterpart, there is no special uppercase version in LaTeX: for example the uppercase of $\alpha$ looks like $A$ (although possibly it should not be italicized) so there is no "\Alpha" command.

This is understandable. However, in many cases I would like a "bigger" version of my Greek letter symbol that is distinct from its Latin counterpart. The one example that really comes to the top of my mind is $\chi$. Chi is used for many things in math/physics/statistics, and it looks particularly bad with subscripts because of how "low" the default letter is. Take a look at how the chromatic polynomial of a graph $G$ is written: $\chi_G(x)$. The $G$ and the $\chi$ sit at almost the same level, even though the $G$ is supposed to be a subscript here. This problem is discussed also at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191551.

It might be a little weird, but you could consider somehow incorporating bigger versions of the lowercase Greek letters that don't have unique uppercase forms. Or at least try to fix chi.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I think the problem with $\chi$ is that it is supposed to descend to the same level as $f$, but since it doesn't also ascend to the same level as $f$, subscripts end up appearing weird, e.g. $\chi_G$ vs. $f_G$. Maybe a solution could be having the subscripts for $\chi$ placed lower to account for this, or have $\chi$ not descend as much. I'll experiment with this to figure out the relative advantages of each approach when implementing it.

Comment: On the bigger versions of the other Greek letters, could you give me some examples of situations where you wanted to use them, or found having them at hand would benefit the exposition?

Comment: Possibly a solution is just to make \Alpha produce A, \Beta B and so on. I guess this is easy to do with a LaTeX macro, and not necessarily something related to fonts. In that case, the issue with $\chi$ extending too far below the line is maybe orthogonal. I guess extending this request, it would be nice to make sure most symbols have a consistent placement, even if this goes against the way they are normally handwritten, because in math subscripts and superscripts are used so often and so having the relative vertical placement of symbols be consistent is important.

Comment: Is the subscript issue really a problem with $\chi$ specifically? Do you also want to similarly "correct" $g_G$, $p_G$, $q_G$, $y_G$? If so, then that seems to be something you'd want to fix in $\rm\TeX$ rather than in the font.

Comment: @TimothyChow: Fair point, and I don't know if this is really a font issue vs. a TeX issue. But yes to me none of those look quite as bad as $\chi_G$ does.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this has been mentioned, but many mathematicians are missing a `\bigtimes` similar to `\bigotimes` = $\bigotimes$.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'll be sure to implement it as well.

Comment: A [TeX.SE discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132251/how-do-you-produce-sign-for-set-multiplication-from-old-math-book-in-latex "How do you produce sign for set multiplication (from old math book) in LaTeX?") (that I discovered through @MichaelHardy's currently HNQ [A MathJax/LaTeX question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5862/a-mathjax-latex-question)) mentions `\varprod`.

Comment: In the same fashion, one misses `\bigast`, as a larger `\ast`$=\ast$, which typically denotes the free product of groups.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be an answer to your questions, but it is also too long for a comment. I hope it can be useful, so I leave it here.

First of all, your font looks nice, so I hope you keep up the hard work!

The most important point: I see nobody commenting on the format. If I were to make a math font today, it would certainly be a Unicode math font. There are several reasons for this, one being that most of the symbols people ask for (and many that nobody ask for) do indeed have their slots there. Let me give a few examples in images below, where I have used the Stix Two Math font, which is rather complete.

Left pointing arrows as accents:

[image: leftpointingarrows]

Wreath product (not the symbol asked for, but this one is the one from the official slot U+2240, you could in your font design a better symbol, or having the standard one with an alternative one that people can use):

[image: wreath product]

Cyrillic can be there (as well as all capital greeks):

[image: cyrillic]

Less than or equivalent to:

[image: lessthanorequivalentto]

Independent symbol:

[image: independent]

Various binary symbols (note here that Stix (top) is not having them uniform while Latin Modern (bottom) do)

[image: binarysymbols]

One more reason to stay within the bounds of Unicode math is accessibility. If one wants to have the possibility to copy and paste from pdf files it is crucial. If one only cares about the output in the pdf, this is not a big problem.

There are also draw backs with Unicode math. Many alphabets exist, but some are lacking (bold sans greek exist, but sans greek does not, to give an example). It is still possible to use private ranges to make them available for macro packages, but then one should remember that one will not be able to copy and paste and keep their meaning. Another bad thing is that there are gaps in the alphabets. So, italic h is not between italic g and italic i, but somewhere else, because it goes as the Planck constant and the Unicode consortium decided against more than one slot that look the same, or something like that. Bad.

When it comes to implementation, the different existing Unicode math fonts do things a bit differently, and therefore some combinations render a bit bad sometimes. One thing is italic correction. An excessive use of it can make important characters like italic f to be hard to use:

[image: fff]

The top line here is (f) in TeX Gyre Bonum Math. It relies heavily on italic correction. On the second line it is how a fixed version can look like. In the third line we see the same expression in Lucida Bright Math. In that font no italic correction at all was used for these kind of symbols, and it still looks very good. Thus, a suggestion is to not make your font depend heavily on italic correction.

When it comes to optical sizes, I would probably not go through the hassle of having and maintaining several versions. The same probably goes through when it comes to bold math. Maintaining a complete bold font seems to be a lot of work. One can already today fake the original font into a slightly bolder one, and for the rare usage in titles, I think it comes out good enough:

[image: bold in math]

A few general (perhaps obvious) suggestions:

- Use many variants for delimiters before going extensible. This is in particular important for the ones that are difficult to have as extensibles (angular brackets for example).
- Make sure that all the accents that can be made to grow do so.
- Add style alternatives for characters that need them. For example the wreath product seems to be one of them. It is then up to the user to choose.
- There are no slots for the calligraphic alphabet, only for the script one. Make sure to add both a calligraphic and a script alphabet. Make one of them a style alternative of the other (this is how it is done in Stix two math). Then the macro packages can make both available, one via `\mathcal` and the other via `\mathscr`, for example.
- Be careful where you set the accent anchors, and do set it for all alphabets, not only for the latin italic ones.
- Make the look consistent. The best way to test is probably by using available articles that use various symbols already.

There is much more to say, but I stop here. I look forward to see your new font!

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed reply and for the encouragement, mickep! (And let me also apologise for taking a little bit to reply; I had to deal with some life stuff that precluded me from replying sooner)

Comment: I'm not too sure about this point yet as I have only been working on designing the text fonts for now, but the main point that worries me with designing "Darwin Math" as a unicode open type math font is that I'm not sure it will work with pdflatex, which is absolutely crucial in order for the font to be used in papers appearing in the arXiv, which doesn't yet support LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX as compilers. (Is this indeed the case, that it is not possible to implement unicode opentype math fonts with pdflatex?)

Comment: So, assuming this is indeed the case, my current plan is to implement it first on pdflatex, and then later perhaps reimplement it also as a unicode math font for use with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: > _There is much more to say, but I stop here. I look forward to see your new font!_ First of all, thank you so much for the encouragement, I hope you'll like the final result once it's ready! Second, let me say that I'm all ears in case you'd like to say more, I'm really grateful for your suggestions, and will always be eager to hear them! Again, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

One point which I want to clarify is that of special and unusual symbols for variables or objects: besides the relatively common ones I mentioned in the question body, such as ш for the Tate–Shafarevich group or よ for the Yoneda embedding, there are a few articles that use even more specific characters, such as:

- Fiorenza–Loregian's [*Recollements in stable $\infty$-categories*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.03913v2), which uses the Georgian letter რ for "a (donné de) recollements";
- Fiorenza–Loregian–Marchetti's [*Hearts and towers in stable $\infty$-categories*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04658v3), which uses the kanji 切 for the "class of slicings of stable $\infty$-categories";
- Some articles relating to the work of Satake, such as those involving Satake compactifications, the Satake isomorphism, etc. use the katakana サ, e.g. Namikawa's [Toroidal Compactification of Siegel Spaces](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0091051);
- Some articles use Hebrew letters that are not conventionally used in mathematics, such as Tsadi (צ) and Mem (מ);
- I've used the kanji 忘 (from 忘れる, *to forget*) in my own work to denote forgetful functors.

I plan to support such usage as well in the form of requests in cases where such unusual notation is reasonable/beneficial. Such requests could either be opened as issues in the GitHub tracker for the font (a link will be added here as soon as it's ready), or by just communicating it to me by email, Discord, etc.

Comment: 切 and 忘 are also the Chinese words for "slice" and "forget." That could be considered an advantage or a disadvantage. It might be confusing, in a mathematical paper written in Chinese, for a Chinese word to be used as a symbol. In English, it would be akin to letting forget denote a forgetful functor.

Comment: @TimothyChow I had never wondered what notations like this would look like in a paper fully written in Chinese or Japanese. I think in Japanese it would either look okay and not be confusing or at there would be simple ways to write for it not to be confusing.

Comment: For example, "Let 忘 be a forgetful functor" would be written as "忘を忘却関手とする", which looks kinda bad and confusing, specially because the "forgetful" in "forgetful functor" is written "忘却", using 忘 itself. However, to avoid confusion we could write it like e.g. 1) 「忘」を忘却関手とする 2) 『忘』を忘却関手とする or 3) 忘$\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathsf{Sets}$を忘却関手とする, all of which look mostly okay I think.

Comment: That said, I don't really know enough about Chinese (be it Mandarin Chinese or any other dialect) to say for sure whether such notation would be a good idea =/

Comment: Here's an idea (not necessarily a good idea, but something to think about): maybe the kanji / Chinese character could be italicized, just as we typically italicize variable or function symbols.

Comment: @TimothyChow Thanks for the suggestion, Timothy! :) I'm afraid this would probably cause more confusion than solve, since Chinese and Japanese have never used italics, nor have an alternate script functionally equivalent to it =/

Comment: (Though it is with great pain that I acknowledge this, I must have wished Japanese had italics instead of just a (so-called) [emphasis mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis_mark) more times than I can count―that would be so nice!)

Comment: Chinese may not "officially" use italics, but advertising billboards and logos have used slanted characters as an attention-grabber since time immemorial. One example that comes to mind is the logo for Coca-Cola, [可口可樂](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/d/dd/Coca-Cola_China.svg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/640?cb=20140702183329), which as you can see is distinctly slanted.

Comment: @TimothyChow Ah, you're right. Hmmm, I think I'll try asking a couple Chinese/Japanese mathematicians and a couple Chinese/Japanese type designers about their opinion on 1) using Kanji/Hànzì on math papers and 2) italicising them as a way to avoid confusion. I hope this will help me figure out what would be a good way to proceed with this, design-wise. Thank you so much for letting me know about this, Timothy, I really appreciate it! :)